# Xcode 10 how to pull from github to local

Tags: github, xcode10

I have check online but all the tutorials are about push.

I don't know how to pull from github to local.
It's not the command line method, but on Xcode 10 UI.
Please teach me how to pull.

Comment: What happens when you choose Source Control > Pull? The following tutorial covers pulling in Xcode: [Understanding Git Version Control and Learn how to Use it in Xcode 9](https://appcoda.com/git-xcode/)

Comment: I have figured it out. When I created a readme file on github, it's in the same repository, but it was not considered in the same project by xcode. 

As a result, when I pull the repository from github, the readme file was downloaded into the folder, but it cannot recognized by xcode, so that in the project view on xcode, all the files created on github would not show there.